# How to create API-15 emulator with Google Play Services (Command Line)

Tags: android, google-play-services, emulation, android-sdk-tools

One user of my app is facing certain issues specifically on `API Level 15 (4.0.4)`, and I would like to reproduce the issue on my end. I don't have a `4.0.4` device, and I would like to create and emulator for this purpose. I'm running `Android Studio 2.0-beta6`, and the `GUI` `AVD Manager` does not show any `API-15` emulator images at all.

So, I have then used the standalone `SDK manager` to install an `API-15` level x86 system image, and then created an `AVD` from command line as follows.

```
$ android create avd -n Api-15-Gnex -t 1
```

Id `1` is the id of the `API-15` target on my machine. But, this system image obviously misses the `Google APIs` in it, and my app depends on `Google Play services`, and I need them specifically to reproduce the issue.

How can I create `API-15` emulator with `Google APIs`? Preferably from command line, but not necessarily.

Comment: "*AVD Manager does not show any API-15 emulator images at all*" did you install the Google APIs of API 15 ?

Comment: Technically, all the download-able images should be listed under images tab in AVD manager GUI.

Comment: @Raptor But, yes, you are right, Google API's actually provide a target, with which I can create an AVD. Trying now. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from Raptor. Through stand alone SDK manager, under API-15, select `Google APIs` and install the package. This adds a new target to the development environment.

```
$ android list targets
  ----------
  id: 5 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:15"
    Name: Google APIs
    Type: Add-On
    Vendor: Google Inc.
    Revision: 3
    Description: Android + Google APIs
    Based on Android 4.0.3 (API level 15)
    Libraries:
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
    Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800
    Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a
```

Note that it is an ARM image, not x86. Since hardware acceleration is not available for APIs less than and including 15, it wont matter, I assume.

Then create a new AVD using this target.

```
$ android create avd --force -n Api-15-Gnex -t 5
    Auto-selecting single ABI armeabi-v7a
    Created AVD 'Api-15-Gnex' based on Google APIs (Google Inc.), ARM (armeabi-v7a) processor,
    with the following hardware config:
    hw.lcd.density=240
    hw.ramSize=512
    vm.heapSize=48
```

Now, you may launch it from the GUI AVD manager.

Comment: for me the resulting AVD doesn't contain Google APIs

Comment: This is what I did : android create avd -f -n my-avd -t android-22 --abi google_apis/armeabi-v7a --sdcard 32M