# Unable to create emulator with Android version 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-4.0.3-ice-cream-sandwich

I need to test my android app with android version 4.0.3 but I am unable to create an emulator with this Android version. Please check following screenshots for more details:

Installed Intel x86 system image for version 4.0.3:
[image: Installed Intel x86 system image for version 4.0.3]

No option for 4.0.3 version while selecting system image:
[image: No option for 4.0.3 version while selecting system image]

Already tried following with no luck:

1. Restarted Android Studio
2. Moved x86 folder from *system-images/android-15/default* to *system-images/android-15* folder

How can I resolve this?

**Edit:**

As suggested by BrentM, I tried to create it using android command line tool. It was successfully created, but when I tried to edit it from Android Studio, then it gives an error: *The specified image file must be a valid image file*.

Address of the image file in system: /Android/Sdk/system-images/android-15/x86

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. After creating the AVD via the command line, find the location of your AVDs. On my Mac they are in the .android/avd folder in my home directory. For reference the name of my new AVD is Api-15-Gnex. I edited two files (I am guessing there is a bug of some sort otherwise this should all be done through GUI). I edited the following two files (change as you see fit for your situation). Below are the how they look like at the end:

1) Api_15_Gnex.ini

```
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
path=/Users/kaamel/.android/avd/Api-15-Gnex.avd
path.rel=avd/Api-15-Gnex.avd
target=android-15
```

2) Api-15-Gnex.avd/config.ini

```
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
AvdId=Api_15_Gnex
abi.type=x86
avd.ini.displayname=Api 15 Gnex
disk.dataPartition.size=4G
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.battery=yes
hw.camera.back=none
hw.camera.front=none
hw.cpu.arch=x86
hw.dPad=no
hw.device.hash2=MD5:6930e145748b87e87d3f40cabd140a41
hw.device.manufacturer=Google
hw.device.name=Nexus 4
hw.gps=yes
hw.gpu.enabled=no
hw.gpu.mode=off
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.lcd.density=320
hw.mainKeys=no
hw.ramSize=512
hw.sdCard=yes
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
hw.trackBall=no
image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-15/default/x86/
runtime.network.latency=none
runtime.network.speed=full
runtime.scalefactor=0.1
sdcard.path=/Users/kaamel/.android/avd/Api-15-Gnex.avd/sdcard.img
skin.name=768x1280
skin.path=768x1280
skin.path.backup=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources/nexus_4
tag.display=Default
tag.id=default
vm.heapSize=48
```

After the edit there were no error and I could edit and/or run it like other AVDs. Just notice that the paths are specific to my setup and you need to change them to yours (like my home directory is at Users/kaamel, or my Android Studio is installed at /Applications/Android Studio.app, etc).

Good luck!

Additional information:

Make sure to check the Api_15_Gnex.ini (or whatever you named your AVD) as well. The last line, "target=android-15", must match the image.file.sysdir.1 target. They both must be the same, in this case android-15. Once you do that, even if you get the error, click on Show Advanced Settings and correct other errors (like skin name, internal storage, etc.) and when there are no more errors click finish and let it regenerate the AVD.

Comment: I checked the file config.ini. The attribute _image.sysdir.1_ already has correct path to system image. So it should not show the message: _The specified SD image file must be a avlid image file_. Isn't it ?

Comment: Make sure to check the Api_15_Gnex.ini (or whatever you named your AVD) as well. The last line, "target=android-15", must match the image.file.sysdir.1 target. They both must be the same, in this case android-15. Once you do that, even if you get the error, click on Show Advanced Settings and correct other errors (like skin name, internal storage, etc.) and when there are no more errors click finish and let it regenerate the AVD. In my case the new AVD worked!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I edited the settings from Show Advanced Settings and then it was successfully created and launched. I suggest you to add this as edit so that others can benefit.

Answer (score 2):

### Change your SD Storage location in Advanced Settings.

I ran into this error as well but found a simple solution that alluded me for a bit.

I didn't know why it was complaining about the SD image but when I hit advanced settings, I could see that the location for the simulator's external SD card image was not valid. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

You could adjust that location but I decided to select the "Studio-managed" option.

Worked like a charm.

This must have occurred during an Android Studio update because I didn't adjust these settings when creating the simulator or since.

Comment: had to adjust the location, not sure how or why the location to sdimage was wrong !!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not seeing the system image in the Android Studio IDE you can create the virtual device using the [android command line tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android.html). Although it is no longer supported, I still use it and it still works.

From the terminal/command line run:

```
android list targets
```

This will list which targets are available, if you have downloaded an API 15 system image through the standalone SDK manager you should see it in the list. Take note of the id of the target you want to use to create an AVD, It should look something like `id: 1 or "android-15"`

Then create the AVD using the id from your list of targets, passing the target id as the -t parameter.

```
android create avd --force -n Android403-Api-15 -t 1
```

Returning to Android Studio, you should now see the AVD listed. You will need to edit the device to finish setting it up with the configuration you required (ie RAM, SD card...).

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35882017/how-to-create-api-15-emulator-with-google-play-services-command-line) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

To use `intel x86` System Image you must install `HAXM` Emulator Accelerator and configure your system BIOS.

for android 4.0.3 you can use `armeabi-v7a` System Image

Comment: But it should work even without HAXM emulator acclerator. Right?

Comment: Yes, Just download armeabi-v7a system image for version of android you like from SDK Manager and create your emulator easily

Comment: Please check the accepted answer's comments. Now I can run emulator with intel x86 system image also. No need of downloading armeabi-v7a system image

Answer (score 0):

Download the x86 image if you have 32 bit computer or try to download x86_64 image with google apis as recommended.